# Google cloud share sheet problem, iam.gserviceaccount.com is not found

Tags: google-drive-api, google-sheets-api, google-apis-explorer

i am trying to work on a python script that interacts with google sheets.

I searched the web for how to do it and followed few tutorials that introduced pretty much the same steps.

Lets take for an example this tutorial:
 https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/02/an-easy-way-to-read-and-write-to-a-google-spreadsheet-in-python.html

i get a problem when trying to share the sheet with the email adress from the json credentials file.

once i hit the “send” button on the share sheet pop up page, i get an error message to my gmail account claiming that the domain at “iam.gserviceaccount.com was not found".

i tried following the steps on other projects as well and the same problem occurs.

I read here an answer for a similar problem, that disable and enable the google compute engine api should make it work, but when i tried doing so a pop up message asked me to add billing account in order to use this api. Do i have to add a billing account in order to share the sheet?

does anyone have any idea on what am i doing wrong and how to fix it?

thanks.

Comment: Did you put the project Id before `iam.gserviceaccount.com`? Like it is explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts#types_of_service_accounts)

Comment: I just checked on it... it did not work any way.

Answer (score 1):

I have spent a good few hours looking for what the problem may be and it turns out that you simply will want to uncheck the [notify people checkbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TI7IX.png) when sharing the spreadsheet with someone